# How to convert formulas to rectified prenex form?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm preparing to an exam and I haven't understood this question:

> Convert the following formulas into rectified prenex form:
>   a) $F = (\forall x \exists y\, P(x, g(y, f(x))) \lor \neg Q(z)) \impliedby \forall x\, R(x, y)$.
>   b) $F = \exists z(\exists x\,Q(x, z) \lor \exists x\, P(x)) \implies \neg(\neg\exists x\, P(x) \land \forall x \exists z\, Q(z, x))$.

Can somebody explain me how to do this?

I'm trying to do the first problem:

So:

$F = (\forall x \exists y\, P(x, g(y, f(x))) \lor \neg Q(z)) \impliedby \forall x\, R(x, y)$.

1. Remove all $\impliedby$ :
   $\neg (\forall x\, R(x, y))\lor   (\forall x \exists y\, P(x, g(y, f(x))) \lor \neg Q(z))$.
2. Push all $\neg$: $(\exists x\, \neg R(x, y))\lor   (\forall x \exists y\, P(x, g(y, f(x))) \lor \neg Q(z))$.
3. Don't understand what is it?
4. $(\exists x\, \neg R(x, y))\lor   (\forall x (\exists y\, P(x, g(y, f(x))) \lor \neg Q(z)))$.
   $(\exists x\, \neg R(x, y))\lor   (\forall x (\exists y\,( P(x, g(y, f(x))) \lor \neg Q(z))))$.
   Here just parethesis?

Comment: Do you know the definition of prenex form? wht did you try? where arr you stuck?

Comment: See [Converting FO Formula to Equivalent Formula in Rectified Prenex Normal (RPF) Form](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/cs513/prenexAlgorithm.pdf)

Comment: I'm trying to understand this paper. What are bound variables and free?

Comment: I have also added my solution for a, but I think this will not be the solution, do you know why?

Comment: Step 3 consists of rnaming bound variables so that each bound var occurs only once and no bound variable also occurs free. In your case, after step 3 we must have : $(∃x¬R(x,y))∨(∀w∃uP(w,g(u,f(w))))∨¬Q(z)$.

Comment: Step 4 means to pull quantifiers out (having renamed the bound variables in order to avoid "dupkications", we can apply the four listed equivalences).